# how override the discussion controller in my new addon using cs cart?

Tags: php, cs-cart

I need to override the discussion controller in my blog addon. how to do.

I have need to override the:

```
$discussion_settings = Registry::get('addons.discussion');
```

this to :

```
$blog_setting=Registry::get('addons.blog');
$discussion_object_types=array_merge($discussion_object_types,$blog_arr);
$discussion_settings=array_merge($discussion_settings,$blog_setting);
```

how to override the discussion controller in my blog addons.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add file app/addons/blog/controllers/frontend/init.pre.php

```
<?php

use Tygh\Registry;

if (!defined('BOOTSTRAP')) { die('Access denied'); }

if (Registry::get('runtime.controller') == 'blog') {

    #get
    $discussion_settings = Registry::get('addons.discussion');

    $blog_setting=Registry::get('addons.blog');
    $discussion_object_types=array_merge($discussion_object_types,$blog_arr); //?????
    $discussion_settings=array_merge($discussion_settings,$blog_setting);   

    #set
    Registry::set('addons.discussion', $discussion_settings);

}
```

Comment: I put this code.But I get  this error message ErrorOops, something went wrong (Internal Server Error). Please try again.

Comment: I test the script on cs-cart 4.2.4 and I assume that the add-on is called blog, please let me know if I miss something

Comment: i get the above error message when override the intit.pre.php or discussion.pre.php

Comment: In blog i need ti implement the comments and review addon also.